# What is ui-datepicker-div and how can I remove it?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

There is a white line bottom of my page, and its div `ui-datepicker-div`

you can look at the website :

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/ ( may it loads slowly, nearly 8 seconds )

I dont know what is datepicker? how can I remove this div to remove white line?

Answer (score 0):

Now a days i can´t look your website, but DatePicker is a Jquery widget.

You can check more information [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

If you need to remove that div, you can do:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').remove()
```